# How to store session data on the client-side regardless of the server domain?

Tags: session, cookies

I would like to store session data for a browser-based control panel of an embedded server. The server can be accessed by its IP, the DNS-provided hostname, and any custom hostnames the user setup.

How would one set a, let's say, a session ID cookie that would be valid on all the accessible hostnames?

Answer (score 0):

`window.name` can hold several megabytes of string data and is server agnostic. The only issue is that it is unprotected, so other sites can read/write to window.name as well.

What you can do is prepend your string data with an identifier; if the identifier is not there, retrieve the data from the server.